# dynamically page load using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-form-helper

helow, I am a newbie in codeigniter. I want to load my pages into my view dynamically. That means, Using a function.
For example i have 4 page home, about, contact, info. In my my view folder I have created a base layout where i include header and footer which is same for all those pages. now i want when i click those page link it just load into content body without loading full page. Using CI normal procedure i can do it. which is

```
function home(){
   $data['main_content'] = 'home';
   $this->load->view('template/layout', $data);
}


function about(){
   $data['main_content'] = 'about';
   $this->load->view('template/layout', $data);
}
```

but i want to create a function which call this pages into a single function for example,

```
function pageload($page){

}
```

this function check that requested file either exits or not exist. if exist it load the page otherwise load "page not found" 404 error page. How can I make it...plz help.

My view file is:

```
                        <nav>
                    <ul class="sf-menu">
                        <li class="current"><?php echo anchor('home/index', 'Home');?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('home/amenities', 'Room & Amenitis');?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('home/reservations', 'Reservations');?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('home/photos', 'Photographs');?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('home/pakages', 'Pakages');?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('home/explore', 'Explore');?></li>
                        <li><?php echo anchor('home/contact', 'Contact');?></li>
                    </ul>       
                </nav>
```

And Controller:

```
    <?php
```

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function pageload($page){
        $data['main_content'] = $page;
        $this->load->view('template/layout', $data);            
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Codeigniter already does everything you want. If you don't have a controller (or the appropriate function in that controller) it will generate a 404 error page. And you don't have to write any code at all.

Comment: I know it Dwayne but my question is that how can i load all of my pages using a single function.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Maybe you could expand on it or provide some larger context.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something lilke this

```
function pageload($page){
   $data['main_content'] = $page;
   $this->load->view('template/layout', $data);
}
```

if u dont want to show controller_name/pageload in url then in application/config/routes.php
add an array

```
$route['(home|about_us|other_page|another_page)'] = 'controller_name/pageload/$1';
```

and to load your 404 page just go to the application/config/routes.php
find this line `$route['404_override']` and set its value to snything u want like

```
$route['404_override'] = 'page_not_found';
```

then in your controller just add a controller named page_not_found.php and load ur desired 404 custom view from that controller.

Comment: How can i catch value into $page variable from my page link?

Comment: just in your url type ur `http://site_name/controller_name/home` or `http://site_name/controller_name/about_us`

Comment: sorry my mistake use this url instead to access 
`http://site_name/home` or `http://site_name/about_us`

Comment: it's not working now when i click my page link suppose, <li><?php echo anchor('home', 'about');?></li> I get only home controller not the page from that controller.

Comment: your view file should be of the same name as that u mention in your url and in your routes.php file...foe example if u create array as `$route[(home|about_us)] =  'controller_name/pageload/$1';`
then home page should be home.php and about us page is about_us.php

Comment: hey Bad developer it's not working. if you want i can mail my full source code to you.

Comment: Ok .. my email mohany2712@gmail.com. Just let me know once u have mailed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function i think this will help you

```
function build_view($flake) {
    $this->data['content'] = $this->load->view($flake, $this->data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('header', $this->data);
}
```

after you add this you need to add to other function like in index function

```
function index(){
     $this->$data['main_content'] = $page;
     $this->build_view('template/layout.php')
}
```